# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' for python

Tags: python, class, types, multiple-instances

```
class Time:
    """The time class defines the time with the following attributes:
    hour ,minutes , second
    """
    def __init__(self,hour=12,minutes=0,seconds=0):
        self.hour = hour
        self.minutes = minutes
        self.seconds = seconds

    #attributes
    hour = 12
    minutes = 0
    seconds = 0

    def get_hour(self):
        return self.hour

    def get_minutes(self):
        return self.minutes

    def get_seconds(self):
        return self.seconds

    def print_time(self):
        print(self.get_hour()+":"+self.get_minutes()+":"+self.get_seconds())

    def set_hour(self, new_hour):
        self.hour = new_hour

    def set_minutes(self, new_minutes):
        self.minutes = new_minutes

    def set_seconds(self, new_seconds):
        self.seconds = new_seconds

    def increment_seconds(self):
        if self.seconds == 59:
            self.seconds = 0
            self.minutes = self.minutes + 1
        else:
            self.seconds = self.seconds + 1
    def increment_minutes(self):
        if self.minutes == 59:
            self.minutes = 0
            self.hour = self.hour + 1
        else:
            self.minutes = self.minutes + 1
    def increment_hour(self):
        if self.hour == 12:
            self.hour = 1
        else:
            self.hour = self.hour + 1

print("making 2 instances of time")
time1 = Time()
time2 = Time(14,34,12)
print("this is before")
print("normal time",time1.print_time())
print("user time",time2.print_time())

time1.increment_hour()
time1.increment_minutes()
time1.increment_seconds()
print("after")
time1.print_time()


time2.increment_hour()
time2.increment_minutes()
time2.increment_seconds()
print("after")
time2.print_time()
```

so im trying to make a class for time and there are its functions etc etc but im trying to also create 2 instances of time one with defult and one with user defined. I thought it was correct but i keep getting this error. Any help

Comment: as the error say, you can't add strings and ints.

Comment: Can you supply more information? What line causes the error?

Comment: It's in the print_time function. I already answered his question, may he'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
print(self.get_hour()+":"+self.get_minutes()+":"+self.get_seconds())
```

You concatenate str-type and int-type with the operator plus(+) ":" <-- str + self.get_seconds() <-- int

So you have to write:

```
print(str(self.get_hour())+":"+str(self.get_minutes())+":"+str(self.get_seconds()))

a = 3
b = "test"

print a + b <-- this is not working (str + int)
print str(a) + b <-- this is working (str + str)
```

That's why it says: unsupported operand for type(s)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're unfamiliar with how to concatenate/interpolate data into strings. In Python, you can't use `+` to concatenate strings unless both operands are strings. Moreover, concatenation is not really idiomatic in Python and people usually prefer interpolation/formatting.

You have two options in this case:

1. Using string interpolation:

   ```
   def print_time(self):
       print("{0}:{1}:{2}".format(self.get_hour(), self.get_minutes(), self.get_seconds()))
   ```
2. Using the string `.join` method:

   ```
   def print_time(self):
       print(':'.join(self.get_hour(), self.get_minutes(), self.get_seconds()))
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The traceback is telling you everything you need to know. You're attempting to add a string to an int. The most obvious place that's happening is here:

```
def print_time(self):
        print(self.get_hour()+":"+self.get_minutes()+":"+self.get_seconds())
```

Here's one possible fix:

```
def print_time(self):
        print('{}:{}:{}'.format(self.get_hour(), self.get_minutes(), self.get_seconds())
```